# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 7): Christmas Settings

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, seasonal, humor

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/81979). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118938/81979) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118955/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-8-dash-away-dash-away-dash-away-all)</sub>

---

[image: xkcd:christmas-settings]

So the question is:

> **Who might have changed the Christmas settings?**

---

<sup>Close-up shots: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atsUX.jpg), [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkzjC.jpg), [(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV1lk.jpg), [(4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj3Q1.jpg)</sup>

<sup>**This puzzle is based on the xkcd comic: [Christmas Settings](https://xkcd.com/1620) by Randall Munroe.*</sup>

Comment: Sorry if the image quality is too low. Here are some other editions of the (same) image: 
[(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB98p.jpg), [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpzCR.jpg),[(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E3tg.jpg). And hopefully, close-up images will be helpful, if these are not. Please let me know if anything is illegible.

Comment: Well, I like the idea of the comics, for sure!

Comment: Did you scan these or draw them online?

Comment: @parz I scanned them. Everything is hand-drawn except header and footer.

Comment: It’s really well drawn. I, however, can’t draw to save my life… kudos!

Comment: (Feel free not to clarify this if it's not meant to be clear.) Are we meant to understand that the New Year settings _haven't_ been changed?

Comment: the art is gorgeous!

Comment: Thanks @Spencer :) So is [yours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119116/81979)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice that

> each dial has 10 settings, and the examples whose labels are shown have the labels in a consistent alphabetical order around the dial.

This suggests

> numbering each dial 0..9 in that order and looking at the digits.

The Christmas settings are

> ```
> 0 3   0 8   1 8
> 0 9   1 9   2 0
> 0 9   0 1   1 4
> ```

and the New Year settings are

> ```
> 1 4   0 5
> 2 3   2 5
> 0 5   0 1
>    1 8
> ```

Hmm,

> the left-hand ones in each pair are always 0,1,2. Maybe these are 2-digit numbers. Interpreting as A1Z26 gives us
>
> ```
> C H R
> I S T
> I A N
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> N E
> W Y
> E A
>  R
> ```

suggesting that the person who changed the settings

> replaced CHRISTMAS with CHRISTIAN. Perhaps they're very religious. Or perhaps the settings always have to form a word, and this was their best way of getting the specific changes they want. Having the settings at CHRISTMAS would have had (from M) coal for Black Hat and Santa entering through the chimney, and (from S) Santa using a sleigh.

So an obvious guess is that

> the change was made by Black Hat, who is hoping for something other than coal this Christmas despite being (as shown in many xkcd comics) a very naughty boy indeed

and OP has confirmed that this is the intended solution. But there's another that I personally like better!

> The dial's set to give Beret coal in his stocking. As we have seen at https://xkcd.com/1282/, Beret has some unusual preferences and sometimes prefers what's meant to be the booby prize. Perhaps the mysterious meddler is Beret, who *really likes coal*.