# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 9): International Christmas Crossword

Tags: word, knowledge, language, crosswords, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118955/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-8-dash-away-dash-away-dash-away-all) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118975)</sub>

---

[image: International Christmas Crossword]

| Languages | Clues |
| --- | --- |
| Arabic | You don’t need to have ailurophobia to be afraid of this Christmas feline. |
| Danish | Church containing the grotto where Jesus was born |
| Finnish | This was the most popular non-alcoholic drink in its region before tea took over. |
| German | A goat-man Christmas figure |
| Greek | This tree usually flowers around Christmas which led to its association with the holiday. |
| Icelandic | Short mythical creature with a white beard usually wearing a conical cap |
| Italian | Rectangular wafer with religious imagery |
| Māori | Grain dish with sweet gravy served during the holiday season or as part of a funeral feast |
| Polish | A glass version of this food item is sometimes hidden on a Christmas tree. |
| Russian | A hidden coin in this cake is supposed to bring fortune to the one who finds it on New Year’s Day. |
| Ukrainian | A type of sweet bread often served dusted with icing sugar at Christmas |

- The languages above are provided in alphabetical order while the clues are in no particular order. Do not assume a relationship between languages and clues which happen to be aligned together horizontally.
- Each language and clue is to be used once.
- For languages that have upper and lowercase letters, use uppercase.
- For languages that have different variants of a letter depending on its position in the word, use the default or standalone variant.
- If you are solving the puzzle using a keyboard, use a sans-serif font (e.g., Arial).

---

If you prefer, you can use [this spreadsheet on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YIIB65Hc2lhrFWrfIN3BYK5yP3YzR47YoupZ3VvLcu0/edit#gid=722727134) to solve the puzzle.

It is not directly editable so you can use the menu option File > Make a Copy. Or, if you have your own spreadsheet for solving puzzles, you can copy everything, change the width of columns and height of rows to 35, and center align the cells horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Our reward for solving this puzzle is

> **CONGRATULATIONS!**

The clues solve like this

> **[JÓLAKÖTTURINN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_Christmas_folklore#The_Yule_Cat)**   (Icelandic) You don’t need to have ailurophobia to be afraid of this Christmas feline.
> **[المهد](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%83%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%B3%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%87%D8%AF)**            (Arabic)    Church containing the grotto where Jesus was born
> **[СБИТЕНЬ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbiten)**      (Russian)   This was the most popular non-alcoholic drink in its region before tea took over.
> **[JOULUPUKKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joulupukki)**   (Finnish)   A goat-man Christmas figure
> **[PŌHUTUKAWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrosideros_excelsa)**   (Māori)     This tree usually flowers around Christmas which led to its association with the holiday.
> **[NISSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisse_(folklore))**        (Danish)    Short mythical creature with a white beard usually wearing a conical cap
> **[OPŁATEK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_wafer)**      (Polish)    Rectangular wafer with religious imagery
> **[КУТЯ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kutia)**     (Ukrainian) Grain dish with sweet gravy served during the holiday season or as part of a funeral feast
> **[GEWÜRZGURKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_pickle)**  (German)    A glass version of this food item is sometimes hidden on a Christmas tree.
> **[ΒΑΣΙΛΌΠΙΤΑ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasilopita)**  (Greek)     A hidden coin in this cake is supposed to bring fortune to the one who finds it on New Year’s Day.
> **[PANDORO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoro)**     (Italian)   A type of sweet bread often served dusted with icing sugar at Christmas

The grid fills in like this

> [image]

And the grey letters

> anagram to **CONGRATULATIONS**!