# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 10): A Cryptmas Carol

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118971) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118984)</sub>

---

The final answer to this cryptic crossword is the name of a Christmas carol, whose three-word title can be extracted from the letters of the grid. I hope you enjoy!

[image]

**ACROSS**
**1** Quote ends up in the Nesbit, Mississippi *Republic* (4)
**3** Boss's travelling between Pennsylvania and Oklahoma identified with old financial record (8)
**9** Let it go: O's exhausted from Foster pitching escapade, giving up 6 after the first (3,4)
**10** Rolled over and skinned after cleaning pointy instrument (5)
**11** School for lad, Yarboro Finishing, to protest over losing second place, in advance (11)
**13** At the moment, me, not I, is used incorrectly (2,4)
**15** *Closer* in Golden, CO revival (6)
**17** *Bachelor* debut: nurse, nun scrambling to overcome blonde's lead; European red-head is a source of heat (6,6)
**20** Amex transaction offers bonus (5)
**21** Clean-cut Partridge Family opener covers Outfield after Weir's last-second cancellation (4,3)
**22** Seeing Wounded Knee in a day provides time to relax (8)
**23** Location decreasingly used for music club closing down? (4)

**DOWN**
**1** Sewer crochets eyelet stitches at first, setting up loops (8)
**2** Donation to bird rehab returned with neither envelope nor enclosed letter of introduction (5)
**4** Mania treated with drug injection results in a lack of vigor (6)
**5** Vacuum devices fill small plastic cups with bad pinot and rum; Merry's third is spit out (7,5)
**6** Bloom concealed by whorl and ovary (7)
**7** Crazy text saying yes includes two emoji hearts (4)
**8** Fear losing primary right to life in Mississippi? Perspicacious. This is a sign something is wrong (5,7)
**12** Superb rectifier with reduced voltage fluctuation (8)
**14** Agent utters wanton nonsense at closing (7)
**16** Spread lies about situation, ultimately! (6)
**18** English supermodel reflected on initially supporting Bowie's choice of spouse (5)
**19** Cat-call disturbs women no end (4)

**EDIT NOTES**:

1. Fixed bad positioning of 1 down clue, and added higher resolution image for grid.
2. Edited enumeration for 21A. It can work with the previous (7), but (4,3) is likely more natural.

**HINT-ISH**

> The instructions indicate that the answer can be extracted from the letters in the grid. They do not indicate where the instructions for picking which letters are used come from. This distinction is deliberate and important.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is clever and very nicely constructed by the OP! The carol hidden within this puzzle is:

> **[WE THREE KINGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Three_Kings)**

The completed grid:

> [image: Completed crossword grid]

Clue explanations:

> **ACROSS**
>  1 **Quote** ends up in the Nesbit, Mississippi Republic (4) **CITE** = (_E _T _I _C)<
>  3 Boss's travelling between Pennsylvania and Oklahoma identified with **old financial record** (8) **PASSBOOK** = PA (Pennsylvania) + BOSS* + OK (Oklahoma)
>  9 **Let it go**: O's exhausted from Foster pitching escapade, giving up 6 after the first (3,4) **SET FREE** = F(-o)STER* + E(-scapad)E
>  10 Rolled over and skinned after cleaning pointy **instrument** (5) **CELLO** = C(-leaning) + (-r)OLLE(-d)<
>  11 School for lad, Yarboro Finishing, to protest over losing second **place, in advance** (11) **PREPOSITION** = PREP (School for lad) + (-Yarbor)O + SIT IN (protest) containing (-l)O(-sing)
>  13 **At the moment**, me, not I, is used incorrectly (2,4) **ON TIME** = MENOTI*
>  15 ***Closer*** in Golden, CO revival (6) **ENCORE** = _EN CO RE_
>  17 *Bachelor* debut: nurse, nun scrambling to overcome blonde's lead; European red-head is **a source of heat** (6,6) **BUNSEN BURNER** = B(-achelor) + NURSENUN* containing B(-londe) + E (European) + R(-ed)
>  20 Amex transaction offers **bonus** (5) **EXTRA** = _EX TRA_
>  21 **Clean**-cut Partridge Family opener covers Outfield after Weir's last-second cancellation (4,3) W(-e)I(-r) + P(-artridge)E + OF (Outfield) + F(-amily)
>  22 Seeing Wounded Knee in a day provides **time to relax** (8) **WEEKENDS** = WE(KNEE*)DS
>  23 **Location decreasingly used for music** club closing down? (4) **DISC** = DISC(-o)
>
>  **DOWN**
>  1 **Sewer** crochets eyelet stitches at first, setting up loops (8) **CESSPOOL** = C_ E_ S_ + LOOPS<
>  2 **Donation** to bird rehab returned with neither envelope nor enclosed letter of introduction (5) **TITHE** = TIT (bird) + (-b)(-a)HE(-r) - here, the 'b' and 'r' form the 'envelope' of the returned (reversed) BAHER, and its 'enclosed letter of introduction' is then the first letter within that envelope: the 'a'...
>  4 Mania treated with drug injection results in **a lack of vigor** (6) **ANEMIA** = MANIA* containing E (drug)
>  5 **Vacuum devices** fill small plastic cups with bad pinot and rum; Merry's third is spit out (7,5) **SUCTION PUMPS** = S (small) + CUPS* containing PINOT(-r)UM*
>  6 **Bloom** concealed by whorl and ovary (7) **[ORLANDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_Bloom)** = _ORL AND O_
>  7 **Crazy** text saying yes includes two emoji hearts (4) **KOOK** = KK containing 2x (-em)O(-ji)
>  8 Fear losing primary right to life in Mississippi? Perspicacious. **This is a sign something is wrong** (5,7) **ERROR MESSAGE** = (-t)ERROR + M(_E)S + SAGE (Perspicacious)
>  12 **Superb** rectifier with reduced voltage fluctuation (8) **TERRIFIC** = RECTIFI(-e)R*
>  14 **Agent** utters wanton nonsense at closing (7) **TRUSTEE** = UTTERS* + (-nonsens)E
>  16 **Spread lies about situation, ultimately!** (6) **SNOWED** = S(_N)OWED &lit!
>  18 **English supermodel** reflected on initially supporting Bowie's choice of spouse (5) **[NAOMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naomi_Campbell)** = (O(-n) in [IMAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iman_(model)))<
>  19 **Cat-call** disturbs women no end (4) **MEOW** = WOME(-n)*

For the extraction of the final answer, I owe its discovery to oAlt in comments below (thanks). What we need to spot is that...

> ...there are words of particular relevance either used outright or hidden secretly among other words in some of the clues. And these words are **gifts from [*The Twelve Days of Christmas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song))**:
>
>  *Day 1:* 21A Clean-cut **Partridge** Family opener covers Outfield after Weir's last-second cancellation (4,3)
>  *Day 2:* 10A Rolle**d ove**r and skinned after cleaning pointy instrument (5)
>  *Day 3:* 1A Quote ends up in t**he N**esbit, Mississippi Republic (4)
>  *Day 4:* 2D Donation to **bird** rehab returned with neither envelope nor enclosed letter of introduction (5)
>  *Day 5:* 15A Close**r in G**olden, CO revival (6)
>  *Day 6:* 9A Let it **go: O's e**xhausted from Foster pitching escapade, giving up 6 after the first (3,4)
>  *Day 7:* 14D Agent utter**s wan**ton nonsense at closing (7)
>  *Day 8:* 3A Boss's travelling between Pennsylvania and Oklaho**ma id**entified with old financial record (8)
>  *Day 9:* 11A School for **lad, Y**arboro Finishing, to protest over losing second place, in advance (11)
>  *Day 10:* 17A Bache**lor d**ebut: nurse, nun scrambling to overcome blonde's lead; European red-head is a source of heat (6,6)
>  *Day 11:* 8D Fear losing primary right to life in Mississip**pi? Per**spicacious. This is a sign something is wrong (5,7)
>  *Day 12:* 5D Vacuum devices fill small plastic cups with bad pinot an**d rum; Mer**ry's third is spit out (7,5)
>
>  What we then need to do is look at the *answers* to these clues and extract the letter in the same position as the day number from the song. So for Day 1's answer, we take the first letter; for Day 2's, we take the second, etc.
>
>  [**W**]IPE OFF
>  C[**E**]LLO
>  CI[**T**]E
>  TIT[**H**]E
>  ENCO[**R**]E
>  SET FR[**E**]E
>  TRUSTE[**E**]
>  PASSBOO[**K**]
>  PREPOSIT[**I**]ON
>  BUNSEN BUR[**N**]ER
>  ERROR MESSA[**G**]E
>  SUCTION PUMP[**S**]
>
>  And taking these letters in order spells **WE THREE KINGS**, the name of our hidden carol! Phew - that was a great way to use the Christmas theme of the PSE Advent calendar to conceal an answer (and makes much more sense of what I had perceived as just some odd wording in some of the clues, ha!).

Comment: good to know I'm not the only one who solved the crossword and has no idea how to find a song title haha

Comment: @juicifer Ha, I've been staring at it so long now, and it's 1:35am so I doubt the brain will fire up any time soon to nail that final answer... but it *might*, so it's refusing to sleep!

Comment: How does "cut Partridge" clue PE, and how does the definition work in 23A? (Edited:) I also want to clarify how "clean pointy" clues C

Comment: @Stiv So the crossword is of course right. But for the final answer, let me say this: based on your most recent puzzle, you are exactly the right person to take the next step.

Comment: @oAlt "cut Partridge" is meant to be Partridge, cut-down...I acknowledge it to be a stretch. For 23A, it is referring to the diminishing sale of CDs in favor of streaming. Re: "clean pointy", pointy as in the front, like pointy end of the spear.

Comment: Aha, I see now. From Jeremy's hint ROT13(V jnf vafcverq gb ybbx sbe uvqqra jbeqf, ohg V qvqa'g abgvpr nalguvat hagvy V jbaqrerq jul "qehzzre" frrzrq gb or uvqqra va gur pyhr sbe 5Q. Fher rabhtu, V sbhaq gur bgure tvsgf sebz Gur Gjryir Qnlf bs Puevfgznf uvqvat va ryrira bgure pyhrf. Rkgenpgvba: tvira gung n tvsg pbzrf agu va gung fbat, gnxr gur agu yrggre bs gur nafjre gb gur pyhr jurer gung tvsg pna or sbhaq (r.t. qehzzre pbzrf gjrysgu fb gnxr gur gjrysgu yrggre bs "fhpgvba chzcf" juvpu vf F). Qbvat guvf sbe nyy gjryir, gur yrggref fcryy bhg va beqre JR GUERR XVATF, juvpu vf vaqrrq n pneby.)

Comment: @oAlt Just woken up and ooh that's a very nice spot! Will complete my answer shortly... Thanks :)

Comment: Well done to OP for that as well :D

Comment: That's it! Props to you and @oAlt!

Comment: I'm a complete noob and am possibly struggling with language, but still don't get a few clues even after explanations. In particular, 1A - ROT13(jurer qbrf RGVP pbzr sebz?); 22A - ROT13(jung nobhg JRQF urer?); 2D - ROT13(eruno erghearq = onure, -rairybcr = nur, -rapybfrq yrggre bs vagebqhpgvba=nu. Rira vs jr punatr qverpgvba ynfg, vg jbhyq fgvyy raq hc orvat GVGUN, ab?).

Comment: @Lodinn No problem; happy to elaborate further (and fix one typo). 1N: '_R _G _V _P' zrnaf gurfr ner gur ynfg yrggref (gur 'raqf') bs gur jbeqf guR arfovG zvffvffvccV erchoyvP, juvpu sbyybj; 'hc' vzcyvrf erirefvat gurz gb trg PVGR. 22N 'JRQF' vf na nooerivngvba sbe 'Jrqarfqnl', gur 'qnl' ersreraprq urer. 2Q Guvf vf n gevpxl bar gb cnefr naq V unq zvfglcrq vg gbb (abj svkrq, gunaxf sbe synttvat vg); gur rairybcr bs 'eruno' erirefrq (v.r. ONURE) vf gur bhgre yrggref, O naq E; vgf 'rapybfrq yrggre bs vagebqhpgvba' vf gur svefg (vagebqhpgbel) yrggre jvguva gung rairybcr, v.r. gur N.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought about that explanation for 22A but it felt a little bit stretchy (I guess 4 letters threw me off a bit). It makes sense now.

Comment: @Lodinn Happy to help :) If you come across other answers you're unsure about while reading through cryptics on this site, do feel free to comment beneath the post to ask for clarifications again - people are usually more than willing to explain; a big part of this community is a focus on good communication and helping others learn about puzzles. (I, for one, have found it incredibly useful for getting to grips with cryptic crosswords - 3 years ago, I found the wordplay explanation notation a completely alien language. I still don't know everything but I'm enjoying learning!)

Comment: @Lodinn To amplify Stiv's point, please never hesitate to ask about clue clarification. I'm normally a bit more libertarian (as Deusovi would say) about cluing than other setters, but in this case I had some constraints that forced me into more complex wordplays than I would have preferred to use. I think they were all fair, but that is a moving and often personal target.

Answer (score -2):

Partial solution:

(Across)

3.

> PASSBOOK

10. 

> CELLO

13. 

> ON TIME

15. 

> ENCORE

17. 

> BUNSEN BURNER

20. 

> EXTRA

22. 

> WEEKENDS

(Down)

4.

> ANEMIA

5. 

> SUCTION PUMPS

6. 

> ORLANDO

7. 

> KOOK

8. (partial)

> ????? MISTAKE

12. 

> TERRIFIC

14. 

> TRUSTEE

19. 

> MEOW

Comment: This might be too partial and you really should add explanations for the clues.