# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 12): Pair up!

Tags: seasonal, printers-devilry

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118984/41973) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119008/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-13-sweden-s-sankta-lucia)</sub>

---

Solve the Printer's Devilry clues and find pairs. What are we listing?

1. Benjamin Franklin was a vocate of free speech (7)
2. Campo Up Company, headquartered in New Jersey, produces canned foods (5)
3. Despite his philanthrophic efforts, some people believed he was the antique, rad in gas, a good person (9)
4. Elton, John W. asked by the Queen in 1998 (5)
5. I understand the plan is not perfect, but nobody has come up with abet tea (4)
6. Many performing magicians rely heavily onto "F" hand (6)
7. Our company is an, ech, firm specialising in electronics components (5)
8. She was a Fo Shu Si, a stand amateur paleontologist (6)
9. Stevie, Ed a contract with Motown when he was only 11 years old (10)
10. The British occupation of be id to the Treaty of Tientsin in 1860 (6)
11. There, IG? No, a Beth! I lasted for 44 years (5)
12. They later moved to Darri to Rial, capital and the largest city on Australia's northern coast (6)

Comment: I think you have a (non-devilish) missing "h" in #3.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Oops, so I did. Fixed now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We are, of course, listing

> Christmas songs.

The pairs:

> 6: SLEIGH (on sleight of hand); 5: RIDE (a better idea)
>  10: JINGLE (occupation of Beijing led); 2: BELLS (Campbell Soup Company)
>  11: FELIZ (the reign of Elizabeth I); 1: NAVIDAD (was an avid advocate)
>  12: WINTER (to Darwin, territorial capital); 9: WONDERLAND (Stevie Wonder landed a contract)
>  8: SILENT (a fossil enthusiast and); 4: NIGHT (Elton John was knighted)
>  7: WHITE (a new hi-tech firm); 3: CHRISTMAS (the Antichrist, masquerading as a good person).