# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 15): Candy Cane Crossword

Tags: crosswords, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119014/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-14-lets-decorate-the-tree) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119034)</sub>

---

Solve this small crossword composed of candy canes, then figure out a thematic four-letter word hidden within the grid!

[image]

**Across:**
**1** Eleanor of the Beatles’ *Help!* (4)
**5** Sitcom which spawned the spin-off *Frasier*
**11** Nestlé bar known for it’s bubbly texture
**12** Yell from somebody running to an elevator (4, 2)
**13** St Nicholas, perhaps
**14** Drink
**15** Essential for multiple day hikes
**16** Believe unquestioningly (3, 2)
**17** Rubs in
**20** Center of excellence?
**21** Number at the top of many clocks
**22** Feature of many online profiles
**25** It might result in +1 or -1
**27** Richard Whiteley and Des Lynam, for *Countdown*
**31** Old-timey chem.
**32** Conceive
**34** Island with a capital on the Indian Ocean
**35** Person stroking domestic animals
**36** Arabic pontificate
**37** Sixth planet from the sun
**38** Earliest epoch of the Jurassic period

**Down:**
**1** Fight against
**2** Close again
**3** Praying statues, in Ancient Greece
**4** Letter between E and W
**5** X, perhaps
**6** Heads straight to location (5, 2)
**7** Napoleon was exiled there
**8** This clue kneads one
**9** Tall Indonesian mountain
**10** Ladders have many of them
**18** One who lives and breathes
**19** 2016 Olympics locale
**22** 2012 Robert Pattinson film (3, 3)
**23** Popular island about 30km from Naples
**24** Not me or you
**26** Traditional Spanish dish made from masa
**27** They don’t lie, per Shakira
**28** Ancient theatres
**29** Badger’s burrow
**30** Nickname of footballer Antonio Pecorari
**33** Enid Blyton character first introduced in *The Mystery of the Hidden House*

Happy holidays and enjoy the puzzle!

Comment: Nice puzzle, certainly one that was in the solving process. Damn the slowness from me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The finished grid:

> [image: Grid]

Notice:

> On each of the four sides, the two answers can be joined into a single word or phrase by adding a letter:
>  BRON + CHEERS -> BRON**X** CHEERS
>  STEP + OTHERS -> STEP**M**OTHERS
>  SATURN + LIAS -> SATURN**A**LIAS
>  BATTLE + HIPS -> BATTLE**S**HIPS
>
>  So the added letters spell out XMAS!

Comment: Whew, that was speedy! 100% correct, good job!